# Checking the intersection of two sets

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

Let $E\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ be a set of the type $I_1\times \dots \times I_n$, where $I_k$ are real intervals, and $X$ be and $n\times p$ real matrix. Suppose also that $rank(X)=p$ and $n>p$. Is there a quick way for checking whether the intersection between $E$ and the space generated by the columns of $X$ is empty or not?

Comment: What can be said about $E$? If it is just an arbitrary set, it will be hard to say if the intersection is empty.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching $E$ is actually a square of the type $I_1\times \dots \times I_n$, where $I_k$ are real intervals.

Comment: This can be solved by linear programming.

Comment: This is a convex feasibility problem and could be solved, e.g. by alternating projections.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Any chances of getting some details on this? It sounds interesting.

Comment: @Dirk Any chances of getting more details about your suggestion? It also sounds interesting.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming gives an overview of the basic theory and known algorithms. If $b,c\in\mathbb R^n$ are vectors such that $I_i=[b_i,c_i]$, your problem is equivalent to the feasibility of the LP $Xx\le c$, $-Xx\le-b$. (This is not in the canonical form as given in the WP article, but one can easily reduce it to that.  Feasibility testing is not really any easier than solving general LP as an optimization problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Emil Jeřábek posted a similar comment while I was writing this…]

Probably linear programming is the simplest way:

Let's say that $I_i = [l_i,u_i]$. Now plug the following linear program into any linear programming solver:
$$
\min_{x,y} 1\quad\text{such that}\quad l_i\leq x_i \leq u_i,\quad \begin{bmatrix} X & -I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y\\x\end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$
If the solver reports infeasibility, then there is no $x$ in the range of $X$ that lies within the bounds given by the intervals, otherwise it should return some feasible vector.

Alternatively you also use alternating projections: Start with some vector $x$ and then perform projections onto $I_1\times\cdots\times I_n$ and the range of $X$ alternatively (the first is a simple clipping while the second is basic linear algebra). If the intersection is not empty, this will converge to something, otherwise, the method will end up alternating between two point that realize the distance of the two sets.

Comment: Of course, you could also use @EmilJeřábek's formulation and use the constraints $l\leq Xy\leq u$.

Comment: Indeed, I will consider both (excellent) suggestions.